# Importing String with variables from Txt file

Tags: string, file, variables

I need to import text from txt file with some variables. I use BufferedReader and File Reader. In code I have :

```
String car = "vw golf";
String color = "nice sunny blue color";
```

And in my txt file:

> I have nice " +car+ " which has "+color+".

My expected output :

> I have nice vw golf which has nice sunny blue color.

My actual output is :

> I have nice " +car+ " which has "+color+".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, what you want to do is replace " + car + " with the value of your car string and likewise for colour.  You've tried to do this by writing your text file as if it were a command to be evaluated.  However, that won't happen - it will just be outputted as is.  I'm going to assume you are using c#.  What you need to do is, prior to outputting your string, parse it to replace the markers with the variables.  I would recommend you get rid of the double quotes in your text file.  You could then do something like this:

```
string text = this.ReadTextFromFile();
string ammended = text.Replace("+car+", car);
```

As mentioned, this is assuming you remove the double quotes from your text file so it reads:

> I have nice +car+ which has +color+.

Also, you don't need to use the + symbols, but I suppose they are a good way of designating a unique token to be replaced.  You could use {car} in the file and then likewise in the Replace startment, for example.

I may not have properly understood what you wanted to do, of course!

**Edit**: Incase of confustion,

> this.ReadTextFile();

was just a short hand way of saying that the text variable contains the contents as read from your text file.

Comment: Judging by the reference to BufferedReader, I guess it's Java. As the user already has the file reading code working, they probably just need: `String ammended = text.replace("+car+", car);`